# Complete the payment process with PayPal Java and get the status whether it is completed successfully or not

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

to integrate PayPal payment into Java web application ,i use this link [Text](https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-into-java-web-application),
but when i verify the paypal sandbox account for both buyer and seller i found the transaction will be added but it has a "pending" status and the money is not changing,so i want to complete the transaction to transfer money from buyer to seller and paypal inform me whether the transaction is successful or not.

Comment: It should be noted that the guide you linked to at CodeJava.net is old, and uses the deprecated v1/payments REST SDK.  You should integrate using the newest v2 SDK, available here: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK.  You'll need two routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ , and the best web approval flow to pair those two routes with is this one: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Answer (score 0):

> I found the transaction will be added but it has a "pending" status

There are a few possible reasons for this, one is simply the expected behavior of `requestPayment.setIntent("authorize");`. You may simply want to change that to "sale" if it's not being captured automatically by the guide you were following.

Another possible reason is the currency if it is new to that sandbox receiver account. Log into the receiver account via https://www.sandbox.paypal.com , and see if you can accept one of the payments in the new currency, which will open a currency balance. Future payments won't be pending.

Also ensure the sandbox Business account receiving the payment has a confirmed email in the sandbox environment...

1. Log into it at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email
2. Send the confirmation from there, if necessary
3. Read and proceed with the confirmation, via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fnotifications%2F

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but the money increase for seller but doesn't decrease for buyer.

Comment: So? The buyer essentially has infinite funding in sandbox, that doesn't matter at all

Comment: the state of transaction does not work     Payment payment = paymentServices.executePayment(paymentId, payerId);
String status=payment1.getState(); status is null

Comment: When you do an v1/payments execute API call, you do get back a transaction status in the REST JSON, but I don't know nor care to know anything about those function wrappers in that deprecated PayPal-Java-SDK.  See my comment above for information about the current v2 Checkout-Java-SDK

Comment: i want to ask you if i can send some extra data to paypal to get it back after payment because the user have to fill out a form before payment .

Comment: You'll need to store the data in your own database, but the variables you can use to reconcile a completed payment with what you stored beforehand in your database are invoice_id/invoice_number (which must be unique for every completed payment on the account), or custom_id (which can be anything)

Comment: i'm truying to use v2 but i can't find  API v2 sdk maven dependency.

Comment: Well I'm not a Java person, but I have Google: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi